# How can I change the font of inline suggestions in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, themes

I am using Fira Code iScript (cursive font) and it's applied to italic style for my textmate scopes.

I've been googling around but can't figure out which setting is controlling the font.

I know using "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes" can help me detect the scope but I can't inspect the ghost text (the inline suggest that cursor can't highlight)
[image: my vs code editor screen]

I've tried finding keywords like "inline suggest", "auto completion" in the settings.json

Comment: I searched "font family" in the VS Code settings and seems like there is no option to control the font of inline suggestions. You can create a new issue in [VS Code's GitHub issue board](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) to request for this feature :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have created the issue in the repo so let's see how the team responds.

Comment: Here's the [GitHub issue link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/180294) for those who are interested

Comment: note that if you actually came here looking for changing the font family of inlay hints, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72126817/11107541.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `editor.inlineSuggest.fontFamily` setting (similar format to `editor.fontFamily`).

The setting was added in response to issue ticket [Allow customizing the font-family for inline completions #201307](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/201307).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the following line into your `settings.json`

```
"editor.inlineSuggest.fontFamily": "'Your Font Family', monospace",
```